# Docker Compose - unable to call container by name

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have following docker-compose config.
Api is php plus Apache, App is node 16 with angular.

version: "3.8"

```
services:
  api:
    build: strap_api
    container_name: strap-api
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    env_file: .env
    volumes:
      - ./backend:/var/www
    working_dir: /var/www
  app:
    build: strap_app
    container_name: strap-app
    volumes:
      - ./frontend:/app/
      - '/app/node_modules'
      - '/app/dist'
    ports:
      - 4200:4200
```

Comand `docker ps` shows me:

```
  CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                        COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS         PORTS                                                  NAMES
  57e172278f5a   strap_image_app   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   6 minutes ago   Up 6 minutes   0.0.0.0:4200->4200/tcp, :::4200->4200/tcp              strap-app
  a9b4011af970   strap_image_api   "docker-php-entrypoi…"   6 minutes ago   Up 6 minutes   0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp, :::8080->80/tcp                  strap-api
```

If I do request to strap-api, response is correct, but for strap-app i always have response `Invalid Host`.

So to call strap-app I need to do it by ip address, and in this case response is correct.

When I enter on container strap-api `docker-compose exec api bash`, I run following command:
`curl http://strap-app:4200` and the result is: `Invalid Host`

Why strap-api can't make a request to strap-app when use url `http://strap-app:4200`

But strap-app can make a request to strap-api using `http://strap-api`

Regards

Comment: What is making a request to `strap-app`? From where?

Comment: @phil from strap-api.

Comment: So your API tries to make a request to the app? That seems a bit odd but please [edit] your question to show how it's trying to make such a request

Comment: I know it's odd, But I need to do it :). But main question is why api can send request if I provide app ip address but it's not possible by container name. I can use ip but then I need to set static ip address in docker network. I wish to avoid it.

Comment: its not odd that you do it, its odd that it doesnt work

Comment: I done it. Is simple curl request.

Comment: I use command docker-compose exec api bash

Comment: I cannot reproduce this using Docker Compose 2.21.0. What version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

1. The `docker-compose` tool is the old standalone python tool and is deprecated. Its fine to just use `docker compose exec` now.
2. Drop the `container_name` directives. Lots of examples use them, they were popularised in a time when the docker compose commands were not complete and frequently docker would be used to act on a compose generated service. However setting a container_name bypasses compose namespaces.
3. Between swarm and compose mode the behaviour of container_name and hostname can be a bit inconsistent. It's much safer to use the service name, or declare a network alias. `http://api` and `http://app:4200` will work as these are the service names.

The network alias approach would entail adding directives something like this:

```yaml
networks:
  api:

services:
  app:
    networks:
      api:
        aliases: [strap-app]
  api:
    networks:
      api:
        aliases: [strap-api]
```

Comment: _"The docker-compose tool is the old standalone python tool"_ depending on how / when OP installed it, it's probably still the Go version. Both Homebrew and Docker Desktop provide the Go version of the `docker-compose` command